# Compiling liquidsoap 1.1.1 on debian jessie

Tags: drupal, internet-radio, liquidsoap

I am trying to compile liquidsoap latest version (1.1.1) on debian latest version (jessy).

I have installed the full package. While running make I get the below error related to shine:

[image]

I have already tried compiling shine API1 and API3 as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: here is the error screenshot:  http://dev.hiretechguys.com/liquidsoap/liquidsoap-compile-error.png

Comment: Crop image as it was mainly a white border.